The Compatibility of IEEE-Access Figure Captions with amsmath
I am using IEEE-Access journal template and whenever I want to insert capital greek letters into the caption of any Figure, I always end up with apostrophe “`” as in the following output:

I wrote down the following Latex instructions to generate the caption above:
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{SampleDERotSymm.pdf}
    \caption{Various solutions of $\Delta$ in \eqref{eqn:sampleDE} under rotational symmetry. The graph of other solutions are derived from the particular solution colored in light blue.}
    \label{fig:SampleDERotSymm}
\end{figure}

What could possibly cause it?

I can reproduce the problem. My advice would be to contact the journal's editorial office, alert them to the problem, and ask them for a fix. For any "field fix" you may choose to implement on your own is likely going to be overridden by the journal's work routines.

@Mico, you are right. I think it is the best course of action, because they will complain if I modify it anyway

I agree with Mico that workarounds could be lost during editing, and that you should contact the journal. For some reason the math font is redefined inside captions, which should not happen.
However, as a workaround: save the symbol that you want in a box and use that box.
\documentclass{ieeeaccess}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\newsavebox{\mydelta}
\savebox{\mydelta}{$\scriptstyle\Delta$}
\begin{equation}\label{eqn:sampleDE}
1+1=\Delta
\end{equation}
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{example-image}
    \caption{Various solutions of \usebox{\mydelta} in \eqref{eqn:sampleDE} under rotational symmetry. The graph of other solutions are derived from the particular solution colored in light blue.}
    \label{fig:SampleDERotSymm}
\end{figure}
\EOD
\end{document}


Note that I made the Delta a bit smaller (with \scriptstyle), the regular character was rather big compared to the rest of the caption (now it is a bit small though).

Thanks @Marijn! It worked out. At least I’ll use it for my own visual purposes. Ultimately, you are both right and I should let them know of it.
